# jquery function call creates multiple instance of countdown timer

Tags: jquery

I actually wanted to have something, where a user can choose a date from jquery datepicker and set the target date for countdown timer.

I already have edited the code from [countdown-jquery from tutorialzine.com](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/12/countdown-jquery/) .

My Code [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/NHRuJ5mL)  and the output you can see [goo.gl/OECkt](http://iboxbd.com/zahid/countdown/custom.html).

Actually put all of your code inside `datepicker onSelect option`. So when i select a date a timestamp is created and countdown timer is initiallized. But the problem is when ever i change the date plugin function is called once again and new instance is created with previous one. That mean it shows two countdown timer in my html page. If i do change the date it shows three countdown timer.

So i need a system where i will change the date and previous instance will be destroyed and new instance will work. The script is actually calling the plugin function by passing parameter. If i can dynamically pass the parameter hope it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do one this : use the below code in your script_new.js before `$('#countdown').countdown({`

```
$('#countdown').html('');
```